# CakePHP Validator not working form entity

Tags: cakephp, quotes, htmlspecialchars

I want to perform a htmlspecialchars with no quotes in my entity save.

Code:

```
$post['body'] = htmlentities($this->request->getData('body'), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Validator doesn't work on save.

How to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `h()` method is just a wrapper for `htmlspecialchars()` more information on that can be found in the Cake API https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#h

```
h(string $text, boolean $double = true, string $charset = null)
```

The long and short of it is that the first parameter for those functions is a string and you are passing in an array of data. If you wanted to strip those out you could override the `patchEntity()` with your own or individual run the special chars function on each elements

Edit: Added more clear example to keep validation

You can use the withData to set the response data and still use patch entities. for instance.

```
$data = $this->request->withData('body', htmlentities($this->request->getData('body'), ENT_NOQUOTES))
```

And then patch/validate the entity using the new request object.

```
patchEntity($post, $data)
```

Comment: If I try  $post['body'] = htmlentities($this->request->getData('body'), ENT_NOQUOTES); the validator doesn't work. Is there any way to make it work - even when the body is the same as the getData?

Comment: You can use the withData to set the response data and still use patch entities. for instance `$data = $this->request->withData('body', htmlentities($this->request->getData('body'), ENT_NOQUOTES))` then use the patch entities with $data as the request. I will edit my post with a more clear example

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting Cannot convert value to string when using $reply['body'] = $this->request->withData('body', htmlentities($this->request->getData('body'), ENT_NOQUOTES));

Comment: @KlaasWaas withData() does not return a string it returns a response object if I recall correctly. Look at my example I updated, it shows the correct usage.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I am now using htmlentities on the view.

Comment: @KlaasWaas not a waste of time at all. Glad you got everything working!